# Getting error in mapreduce without mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, format

I tried to use `KeyValueInputFormat` in the student marks example.
This is the input:

> s1 10 
>   s2  50
>   s3  30
>   s1  100
>   s1  50
>   s2  30
>   s3  70
>   s3  50
>   s2  75

I used the `KeyValueInputFormat` as the input format, so it brings student names(s1,s2...) as the keys and marks(10,50...) as the values. My aim is to find the total marks for each one. So, I used just the reducer as

```
public class MarkReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,LongWritable>{

  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,Context ctx) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    long sum = 0;
    for(Text value:values){
        sum+= Long.parseLong(value.toString());
    }
    ctx.write(key, new LongWritable(sum));
  }
}
```

I neither created nor mention the mapper in the job. I am getting the error

> Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

But If I use a dummy mapper like,

```
  public class MarkMapper extends Mapper<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context ctx) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        ctx.write(key, value);
    }
}
```

I am able to get the proper output. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have stated in your main method that the output of the program will be keys of type `Text` and values of type `LongWritable`. 
By default, this is also assumed to be the output type of the Mapper.

Also, the default mapper (the IdentityMapper) will also assume that the input it receives is also of the same type as its output, but in your case the input and output of the mapper should be key-value pairs of the type `Text`.

So, just add a command in the main method, to specify that the output of the Mapper should be of the form Text,Text:

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

I think this should work. Otherwise, do as Mobin Ranjbar suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
ctx.write(key, new LongWritable(sum));
```

to

```
ctx.write(key, new Text(sum));
```

in your reducer. Or change `reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,Context ctx)` to `reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values,Context ctx)`

Comment: Can you explain that? I have already mentioned that My output value is longwritable in job as job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

Comment: Your reducer/mapper says that the output you want is LongWritable type but you gave me Text. Change `job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);` to `job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);` or change your code as I said.